# How to find what scripts are running at boot?

Tags: scripts, raspberrypi

I recently got a Raspberry Pi that I have been tinkering with. I followed some tutorial I found online and wrote a startup script that opens Chrome to a particular web address. Now, I want to change that address... but I forgot where I saved the address.

Anyway to monitor what scripts are running at boot?

Comment: What desktop environment are you using, assuming you're using one..

Comment: First thing I would try: `grep -R '<current-address-being-opened>' /etc ~`